# The correct usage of What are these? They're hamburgers or They're two hamburgers

Tags: grammar

Students need to answer questions according to the content of certain pictures.
And the question is "What are these?"

Do they answer "They're hamburgers." or "They're two hamburgers."

Comment: How many hamburgers does the particular picture show?

Comment: I would assume that the students are being asked to identify the items rather than count them.

Comment: There are two hamburgers on the picture. And some of the students are counting the objects rather than identifying them. Some parents are calling me to say that I should mark the answer There are two hamburgers right.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I just want to make sure it's grammatically right.

Comment: They are not "two hamburgers". Each object is one hamburger, so the answer to the question "What are these?" should be "They are hamburgers." The answer to a different question might be "**There** are two hamburgers".

Comment: *Do they answer "They're hamburgers." or "They're two hamburgers."* - Neither. The idiomatic response is simply "Hamburgers".

Comment: Either is correct.

Comment: Are you studying grammaticality (they're all grammatical), idiomaticity (go with Greybeard), or the Gricean Maxim of Quantity (specify number also)? Or spotting skills (they're actually samosas)? Or precision of terminology (how is 'hamburger' defined?) Or precise logic (This is a picture of two beefburgers, not the real thing)?

Comment: I had a teacher who warned us that if he asked on a test whether a character with three kids "had two kids," the correct answer was Yes. Don't be that sadist, and do accept all reasonable answers. They're all hamburgers.